# Postgresql - PID in cancel request did not match any process

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

When I tried to kill one idle connection. Using the below query

```
select pg_terminate_backend(24861);
```

I am getting the below log.

```
2021-07-26 18:45:32 UTC:192.168.26.250(56021):postgres@demo_uat:[24861]:FATAL: terminating connection due to administrator command
2021-07-26 18:45:33 UTC:192.168.26.250(59691):[unknown]@[unknown]:[543]:LOG: PID 24861 in cancel request did not match any process
```

It seems like the PID disappears after this query. Because when I run this query again I get the below log.

```
postgres@postgres:[26522]:WARNING: PID 24861 is not a PostgreSQL server process
```

But one more idle connection is being opened under a different PID.

For example, if I have a 400 idle connection and if I kill all those connections using this query

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid) FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE datname = current_database() 
AND pid <> pg_backend_pid()
AND state in ('idle');
```

Then another 400 idle connections are being opened under different PIDs. But I don't see anything in the log like this connection being created.

Any insight on how to solve this error will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Unless log_connections if turned on, there is no reason for new connections to get logged.

Comment: You have not described any errors.

Answer (score -1):

You get `PID 24861 in cancel request did not match any process` if/when at the time you do a `pg_ctl restart -m fast`, you had other application(s) checking out connections to the postgres server.